# Send GPS coordinates over either SMS or Email

Tags: android, ios, email, gps, sms

If I want to send GPS coordinates by either SMS or Email to a recipient, does it exists any standardized formats, so when the recipient receives the coordinates, he is able to just click on the coordinates and the default map app opens? In the same way as it works with links, email addresses or with telefon numbers.

I'm mainly thinking og Android and IOS, but i guess if it is a standardized format it works with other systems aswell.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll find out any standard. WhatsApp handles it perfectly while some other apps don't really.
I think the best way is to use this : https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html
just send your GPS as plain text to whatsapp for exemple. 
if the user selects mail, or sms, you should embbed this in a gmap link for example.